# Android Pull Down To Reveal View From Top of Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, swipe, pull-to-refresh

I have an activity and when user swipe from top to bottom, a view at the top of activity, will go down as how much distance the user swipes. There is similar topics about this issue but they are not exactly what i want. How can i do that.

At the begining the view is outside of Activity. When user start to pull. It will go down at the top of activity and whole view will go down as a portion of slide.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is coming late, but it may help for other one. You can use [this library](https://github.com/chenupt/DragTopLayout)
The result look like this:

[image]

Just change your layout like this:

```
<github.chenupt.dragtoplayout.DragTopLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <!--top view-->
 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:orientation="vertical">
     ...
 </LinearLayout>

 <!--content view-->
 <LinearLayout
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
     ...
 </LinearLayout>
```